# How to move the HEAD to the latest date in git?

Tags: git, head

What I wish to do is to get the version of the file that has a specific comment, get it and use it, then change it to the latest code.

```
git log -g --grep="code submitted version 0.1.2.3"
```

This returns a hash `123456`, then I do:

```
git checkout 123456
```

and use the older version.

Now I want to change the `HEAD` back to the latest. This I could not do.
I have tried:

```
git reset --hard
git clean -f
git pull
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you called `git checkout 123456` you moved your `HEAD` from the commit you were currently on (most likely the head of the `master` branch) to the commit `123456`. Therefor you are looking for a way to move `HEAD` back to the branch you were previously on, which you can do with:

```
git checkout master
```

If you want to take a look at a specific revision of a file, you can either just view it using

```
git show 123456:/txt/file.txt
```

or temporarily check out only this file with

```
git checkout 123456:/txt/file.txt
// use it
git checkout :/txt/file.txt
```

**Explanation of your tries**:

`git reset --hard`

Reverts all changes of the current `HEAD`, but does not move `HEAD`. After a reset, `git status` shows that everything is "clean".

`git clean`

Removes all untracked files from the working tree, again `HEAD` is not moved.

`git pull`

Fetches the upstream changes and merges them in. Not what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Very good explanations. I better not use git show because I have a binary. "git checkout master" works well. I guess it takes some time to get used to git :)

Comment: you can use `git show 123456:/txt/file.txt > newfile.txt` to pipe the output into `newfile.txt`.